# Double each video frame within Blender VSE

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, video

I want to take an input of a video file (or image sequence) and then duplicate each frame. So if I had 3 frames, normally they'd go 1,2,3. After duplicating, I'd have 1,1,2,2,3,3 for a total of 6 frames. Is this possible with the compositor or one of the video editors in Blender, or do I have to go outside Blender?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in the VSE with the *speed control* effect:

1. Select the video strip you want to slow down
2. Add a speed effect strip (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Effect Strip > Speed Control*)
3. Extend the original strip to twice its length

[image]

Comment: For the reverse effect just use the `Strobe` setting in the `Filter` Properties of a strip.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying this and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've got double the frames, but when I render the video clip out, it's not any different from the base clip. And in blender if I arrow key through the frames 1 by 1, it's still a new frame each time. It's not duplicating the frames.

Comment: @Drudge Huh. What happens if you set the speed multiplier to .5 on the speed strip?

Comment: @gandalf3 That seems to have worked, but I'm still not sure. I need to try it on more base footage.

Answer (score 2):

In the new versions of blender (2.9, 3.0, etc.) you can do it in *Video Editing* layout without any modifiers, simply by changing the *Strobe* parameter in the strip's options:

[image]

Maybe my answer will help someone. Hope so :)

Comment: Not a problem to answer old questions :)

Comment: I was trying to do this a couple of weeks ago and gave up because I couldn't make it work. I'll have to go back to that project and try this.